# Showing simple random walk result when the code is running

Tags: matlab

I wrote a code for N simple random walkers in 2D. I don't want to save particles position in all steps, instead, I want to show the position of particles in a movie when the code is running. In this way, I don't need to save information about positions of particles in all steps.

Could anyone help? Could anyone write a code to show the motion of particles in this way?

Comment: You should specify more clearly what you need: what type of random walk? How is each step randomly chosen: Gaussian, uniform, ...? And especially, what have you tried? You should show your attempted code. Please see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @LuisMendo I think OP is interested in the plotting, not in the random walk.

Comment: Why did you just delete the question which was related to this? The detailed response you got could have helped others, and your question writing had improved from this one...

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
figure()
hold on
for ii=1:long_walk

    [x2,y2]=computeLocationOfNextStep(x1,y1);

    plot([x1,x2],[y1,y2],'b');
    plot(x2,y2,'rx');
    drawnow
    pause(0.05) %or longer, I am not your boss

    x1=x2;
    y1=y2;

end
```