# presenting motion of random walkers in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I have simulated some random walkers. I used

> plot(xb,yb,'b--o')

to show particles in each step. I saw a code in below link with beautiful particles with tail which moves in a blur way. Is there a way which I could my random walkers the same as the walkers in the link in mat lab? Could anyone tell me which should I use instead of the plot function I used?

[beautiful particles](http://allanino.me/vicsek-model-simulation/?N=500&n=2.0&v=10)

The code I tried:

```
clear all
close all
lbox=20;

%random fluctuation 
eta = (2.*pi).*.1;
vs=0.02;
n=200;
birdl=[1:n];


axis([0 lbox 0 lbox])
axis('square')
hold on
xb=rand(n,1).*lbox;  %first possition
yb=rand(n,1).*lbox;    %first possition
vxb = 1;
vyb = 1;

for steps=1:5000;
xb = xb + vxb;
yb = yb+ vyb;

for bird1 = 1:n;
%periodic boundary condition
if(xb(bird1)<0);xb(bird1)=xb(bird1)+lbox; end
if (yb(bird1)<0);yb(bird1)=yb(bird1)+lbox;end
if (xb(bird1)>lbox);xb(bird1)=xb(bird1)-lbox;end
if (yb(bird1)>lbox);yb(bird1)=yb(bird1)-lbox;end

end
ang=eta.*(rand(n,1)-0.5);

vxb = vs.*cos(ang);
vyb = vs.*sin(ang);

cla

set(gcf,'doublebuffer','on')

plot(xb,yb,'.b')
%quiver(xb,yb,vxb,vyb,'b')
drawnow
end
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42435693/showing-simple-random-walk-resualt-when-the-code-is-running/42435925#42435925

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to create a sort of trail of where the particles have recently been, you can store the previous `nStore` plots and change their color so that older plots gradually darken and fade to black (alpha transparency like in your sample isn't possible with line objects in MATLAB). Here's a reworking of your code (with a few other improvements, like replacing the inner boundary condition loop with indexing):

```
clear all
close all
lbox = 20;

%random fluctuation 
eta = (2.*pi).*1;
vs = 0.05;
n = 200;

set(gcf, 'doublebuffer', 'on', 'Color', 'k');
set(gca, 'Visible', 'off');
axis([0 lbox 0 lbox])
axis('square')
hold on
xb = rand(n, 1).*lbox;  %first possition
yb = rand(n, 1).*lbox;  %first possition
vxb = 1;
vyb = 1;

hList = [];
nStore = 30;
cMap = [zeros(nStore+1, 1) linspace(1, 0, nStore+1).' zeros(nStore+1, 1)];

for steps = 1:200

  xb = xb + vxb;
  yb = yb + vyb;

  %periodic boundary condition
  index = (xb < 0);
  xb(index) = xb(index) + lbox;
  index = (yb < 0);
  yb(index) = yb(index) + lbox;
  index = (xb > lbox);
  xb(index) = xb(index) - lbox;
  index = (yb > lbox);
  yb(index) = yb(index) - lbox;

  ang = eta.*(rand(n,1)-0.5);

  vxb = vs.*cos(ang);
  vyb = vs.*sin(ang);

  h = plot(xb, yb, '.g', 'MarkerSize', 12);
  if (numel(hList) == nStore)
    delete(hList(nStore));
    hList = [h hList(1:end-1)];
  else
    hList = [h hList];
  end

  set(hList, {'Color'}, num2cell(cMap(1:numel(hList), :), 2));

  drawnow
end
```

And here's an animation:

[image]

I created the animation by adding the following code:

```
% After the drawnow...
frame = getframe(gca);
im = frame2im(frame);
imind(:, :, 1, steps) = uint8(rgb2ind(im, cMap, 'nodither'));

% After the loop...
imwrite(imind(:, :, 1, 1:2:end), cMap, 'randwalk.gif', ...
        'Loopcount', Inf, 'DelayTime', 0);
```

I had to trim out some frames to make the gif smaller.

Answer (score 3):

My shot at "nicer" random walk:

```
clear all
close all
lbox=20;

figure('Color',[0 0 0])

%random fluctuation
eta = (2.*pi).*1;
vs=0.02;
n=300;
birdl=[1:n];


axis([0 lbox 0 lbox])
axis('square')
hold on
xb=rand(n,1).*lbox;  %first possition
yb=rand(n,1).*lbox;    %first possition
vxb = 1;
vyb = 1;

for steps=1:5000;
    xb = xb + vxb;
    yb = yb+ vyb;

    for bird1 = 1:n;
        %periodic boundary condition
        if (xb(bird1)<0);xb(bird1)=xb(bird1)+lbox; end
        if (yb(bird1)<0);yb(bird1)=yb(bird1)+lbox;end
        if (xb(bird1)>lbox);xb(bird1)=xb(bird1)-lbox;end
        if (yb(bird1)>lbox);yb(bird1)=yb(bird1)-lbox;end

    end
    ang=eta.*(rand(n,1)-0.5);

    vxb = vs.*cos(ang);
    vyb = vs.*sin(ang);

    cla
    set(gca,'Color',[0 0 0]);
    set(gcf,'doublebuffer','on')
    set(gca,'YTick',[]);
    set(gca,'XTick',[]);

    plot(xb,yb,'.g','markersize',10)
    % this should draw lines, but its slow and not as neat as a web app
%     plot([xb xb-vxb*5]',[yb yb-vyb*5]','g') 

    drawnow
end
```

[image]

Comment: @oliverrouph MATLAB is not the tool for graphics, but scientific computing. Still, if you take the time to read the code, you can see that I added a rough approach for a tail. Modify as pleased to make that tail nicer.

Comment: @oliverrouph Actually if you uncomment the code you will see the same tails as [in the webpage](http://allanino.me/vicsek-model-simulation/?N=500&n=2.0&v=0.2).