# How to make previous inputs progressively fade out in a Matlab plot when I add new inputs

Tags: matlab, plot, line, transparency, matlab-figure

Let's say I have this very simple loop

```
for i=1:10
    [xO, yO, xA, yA, xB, yB, xC, yC] = DoSomething(i);
    line([xO,xA,xB,xC],[yO,yA,yB,yC]);
    pause(0.1);
end
```

The coordinates that I am plotting correspond to the joints of a multibody system, and I am simulating their positions over time (please see a sample of the plot here):

[image: Periodic plot]

Since some of the links move in a periodic way, it gets confusing to keep track visually of the movement. For this reason, now comes the question: how can I plot the lines in a way that, when a new line is plotted, the previous lines are faded progressively? In other words, so that I have a gradient from the most recently plotted data (most opaque) to the oldest data (increasingly transparent until it completely fades out).

This way when a new line is drawn in the same position as very old data, I will notice that it is a new one.

Comment: What version of MATLAB are you using?

Comment: [Sorta, kinda related.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42438765/52738)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm adding a 2nd answer to clearly separate two completely different approaches. My [1st answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53592440/3978545) uses the undocumented (and as of 2018b, depreciated) transparency option for lines.

This answer offers a different approach for line drawing which has no compatibility issues (these two 'features' could be implemented independently):

- Create a fixed `n` lines and update their position, rather than creating a growing number of lines.
- Recolour the lines, fading to white, rather than changing transparency.

Here is the code, see comments for details:

```
% "Buffer" size, number of historic lines to keep, and governs the 
% corresponding fade increments.
nFade = 100;

% Set up some demo values for plotting around a circle
dt = 0.05; a = 0:dt:2*pi+(dt*nFade); n = numel(a); b = a.*4;
[x1,y1] = pol2cart( a, ones(1,n) ); [x2,y2] = pol2cart( b, 0.4*ones(1,n) ); 
x = [zeros(1,n); x1; x1+x2]; y = [zeros(1,n); y1; y1+y2]; 

% Initialise the figure, set up axes etc
f = figure(1); clf; xlim([-1.5,1.5]); ylim([-1.5,1.5]);

% Draw all of the lines, initially not showing because NaN vs NaN
lines = arrayfun( @(x)line(NaN,NaN), 1:nFade, 'uni', 0 );
% Set up shorthand for recolouring all the lines
recolour = @(lines) arrayfun( @(x) set( lines{x},'Color',ones(1,3)*(x/nFade) ), 1:nFade );

for ii = 1:n
    % Shift the lines around so newest is at the start
    lines = [ lines(end), lines(1:end-1) ]; 
    % Overwrite x/y data for oldest line to be newest line
    set( lines{1}, 'XData', x(:,ii), 'YData', y(:,ii) );
    % Update all colours
    recolour( lines );           
    % Pause for animation           
    pause(0.01);
end
```

Result:

[image: demo]

Comment: Very nice alternative, though I personally would prefer using transparency. In another (perhaps very specific case) where you maybe want to fade in lines, this would mean that you get a slight interruption in the a 'solid' line since it a 'more white' line is drawn over it. Totally not relevant to the question, but just a thought. Very much depends on the specific mechanism, linewidth, and to what degree you are a nitpicker.

Comment: @rinkert Agreed, true transparency is king when doable. I didn't do any real performance tests but in making the above, I think this is slower than the existing answers using transparency too.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, Wolfie. Although I like more the transparency approach, I prefer to this solution since it doesn't use depreciated parameters. Awesome!

Answer (score 19):

You can do this by modifying the 4th `Color` attribute of past lines.

Here's a demo resulting gif, where I faded out 10% of the transparency each frame, so only the most recent 10 lines are visible.

[image: fade plot demo]

Here is the code, see my comments for details:

```
% Set up some demo values for plotting around a circle
a = 0:0.1:2*pi; n = numel(a);
[x,y] = pol2cart( a, ones(1,n) );

% Initialise the figure, set up axes etc
f = figure(1); clf; xlim([-1,1]); ylim([-1,1]);
% Array of graphics objects to store the lines. Could use a cell array.
lines = gobjects( 1, n );
% "Buffer" size, number of historic lines to keep, and governs the 
% corresponding fade increments.
nFade = 10;

% Main plotting loop
for ii = 1:n
    % Plot the line
    lines(ii) = line( [0,x(ii)], [0,y(ii)] );
    % Loop over past lines.
    % Note that we only need to go back as far as ii-nFade, earlier lines
    % will already by transparent with this method!
    for ip = max(1,ii-nFade):ii
        % Set the 4th Color attribute value (the alpha) as a percentage
        % from the current index. Could do this various ways.
        lines(ip).Color(4) = max( 0, 1 - (ii-ip)/nFade );
    end
    % Delay for animation
    pause(0.1);
end
```

You may want to do some plot/memory management if you've got many lines. You can delete transparent lines by adding something like

```
if lines(ii).Color(4) < 0.01
    delete(lines(ii));
end
```

Within the loop. This way your figure won't have loads of transparent remnants.

---

Notes:

- I generated the actual gif [using `imwrite`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imwrite.html#btv452g-1) in case that's of interest too.
- Apparently the 4th Color value 'feature' has been depreciated in R2018b (not sure it was ever officially documented).

Got enough upvotes to motivate making a slightly more fun demo...

[image: fader]

Comment: It seems that line objects are not supposed to support transparency: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/alpha.html#buvaucs-1-obj

Comment: No, I don't. I don't understand why they think only patches need transparency, it certainly is useful for lines as well (had a colleague in the past who used it effectively with [parallel coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_coordinates), for example). In this case it doesn't really need to be transparent, you could instead change the RGB values to approach white.

Comment: @Cris transparency has advantages over colour fading when things overlap for example... Brice's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53592651/3978545) suggested colour fading but he deleted it on my suggestion transparency was simpler (before realising it's no longer supported)

Answer (score 17):

**Solution for Matlab 2018a or later (or earlier, later than 2012a at least)**

Since the fourth color parameter as alpha value is no longer supported in Matlab 2018a (and apparently was never supposed to as Cris Luengo pointed out), here a solution that works in Matlab 2018a using the [`patchline`](https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/36953-patchline) function from the file exchange (credits to Brett Shoelson).

```
% init the figure
figure(); axes();
hold on; xlim([-1 0.5]); ylim([0 1]);

% set fraction of alpha value to take
alpha_fraction = 0.7;
n_iterations = 200;

% looping variable to prevent deleting and calling already deleted lines
% i.e. to keep track of which lines are already deleted
delete_from = 1;

for i=1:n_iterations
    % your x, y data
    [x, y] = doSomething(i);

    % create line with transparency using patchline
    p(i) = patchline(x,y, 'linewidth', 1, 'edgecolor', 'k');

    % set alpha of line to fraction of previous alpha value
    % only do when first line is already plotted
    if i > 1
        % loop over all the previous created lines up till this iteration
        % when it still exists (delete from that index)
        for j = delete_from:i-1       
            % Update the alpha to be a fraction of the previous alpha value
            p(j).EdgeAlpha = p(j).EdgeAlpha*alpha_fraction;

            % delete barely visible lines
            if p(j).EdgeAlpha < 0.01 && delete_from > j
                delete(p(j));
                % exclude deleted line from loop, so edgealpha is not
                % called again
                delete_from = j;
            end
        end
    end
    % pause and behold your mechanism 
    pause(0.1);
end
```

I included the deletion of barely visible lines, as suggested by @Wolfie (my own, perhaps less elegant implementation)

And here a demonstration of a quick release mechanism:

[image: Quick-release-mechanism]

Comment: Nice solution for newer MATLAB versions, annoying how MathWorks removed the alpha functionality, leaving us the FileExchange `patchline` and not a simple native replacement! Thanks for expanding on this alternative in your edit.

Comment: Someone copy-pasted your solution in a FileExchange submission, without attribution:  https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/69816-fadeit